# Bitwise XOR on multiple operands in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

I want to bitwise operate on multiple operands so that the outputed integer has a 1 when only one integer has a 1 bit in this position and 0 otherwise.

I am using:
(a ^ b ^ c ^ d ^ e ^ f ^ g ^ h ^ i) ^ (a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i)

with

```
a: 0000001000
b: 0000000010
c: 1010000000
d: 0000110000
e: 0001000000
f: 0000110000
g: 1000100000
h: 0000000100
i: 0100000000
```

i want to get:

```
   0111001110
```

However, I am obtaining:

```
   0111101110
```

Any idea why? or maybe what should i modify?

Comment: You're going to need a loop to do this, since the terms of each comparison depend on the result of previous comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you *can* calculate that with bitwise operations.

`int atLeastOne = 0` will be a mask indicating bits that are set in 1 or more of the inputs.

`int moreThanOne = 0` will be a mask indicating bits that are set in 2 or more of the inputs.

An input `x` can be "added" to that state with:

```
// if a bit has been set already and it is set again now, it has been set more than once
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & x;
// if a bit is set now, it is set at least once
atLeastOne |= x;
```

Just do that with everything (with simplification at the start):

```
atLeastOne = a;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & b;
atLeastOne |= b;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & c;
atLeastOne |= c;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & d;
atLeastOne |= d;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & e;
atLeastOne |= e;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & f;
atLeastOne |= f;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & g;
atLeastOne |= g;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & h;
atLeastOne |= h;
moreThanOne |= atLeastOne & i;
atLeastOne |= i;
```

A bit has been set *exactly* once if it has been set at least once *and* no more than once:

```
int exactlyOne = atLeastOne & ~moreThanOne;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this:

```
int a = 8;
int b = 2;
int c = 640;
int d = 48;
int e = 64;
int f = 48;
int g = 544;
int h = 4;
int i = 256;
int result = 0;
int [] arr = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};

// go through all positions
for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
    int ones = 0;
    // go through each number for this position
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    {
        int val = arr[k] & (1 << j);
        ones += (val > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    result += (ones == 1) ? (1 << j) : 0;
}
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

**Outputs**:

```
462
111001110
```